# Upgrading jboss server 4.0 with jdk6 to wildfly15 with jdk8

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, struts-1, jdk6

previously my project was on jdk 6 with jboss 4.i upgraded from jdk6 to jdk8 . When i was using jdk 8 with jboss4 it was working properly but after upgrading jboss 4 with wildfly 15 i am getting below error.
in web.xml i configured crystalReportViewer as given below .wildfly 15 is giving error  but when i removed the crystalReportConfiguration line then its working properly..

enter code here

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_image_uri</param-name>
    <param-value>crystalreportviewers</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</param-name>
        <param-value>webapp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet from
>   [Module "deployment.ubarms.war" from Service Module Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:437)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:278)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:109)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
>     ... 8 more

Comment: Is the `com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet` class defined in the `ubarms.war` ?

Comment: we have add all the required jar in the classpath and also configured its required configuration and it was working with jboss 4 but when i upgraded with wildfly 15 then it is showing class  not found....above error....

Comment: How do you define that classpath? The error complains about not finding the `CrystalReportViewerServlet` class when trying to deploy `ubarms.war`, so it would help if you could detail how `ubarms.war` is supposed to have access to the class.